# Css dynamic font-size

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I try to make a special screen very dynamic in `AngularJS`.

I this screen there is some object with a define size:

```
.item
{
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 11vw;
  height: 11vw;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

There items was insert by an ng-repeat loop base on the return of an `API`.

```
  <div class="item"
       ng-click="ctrl.clickFunction()"
       ng-style="{'background-color':ctrl.color }">
    <div class="itemGlobalCode">{{::ctrl.name}}</div>
  </div>
```

Problem is my items were round and to have a best render I'd would like to change the font size of the content (here ctrl.name) if this content was to long to fit the container.

I find some `jQuery` solution but if it's possible I'd would like to avoid them and if it's possible I'd would like an pure `CSS` solution.

Have you some idea ?

Comment: Snipped it, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a expression on ng-style:

**Ternary**

```
<div class="itemGlobalCode"
     ng-style="{'font-size': ctrl.name.length > 10 ? '12px' : '14px'}"></div>
```

**Method**

Controller

```
$scope.getFontSize(ctrlName) {
    if (ctrlName.length > 10) {
        return '12px';
    }

    return '14px';
};
```

View

```
<div class="itemGlobalCode"
     ng-style="{'font-size': getFontSize(ctrl.name)}"></div>
```

**Plus: ng-class**

You can also create classes with differnt font-sizes:

**CSS**

```
.itemSmall {
    font-size: 12px;
}
.itemBig {
    font-size: 14px
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="itemGlobalCode"
     ng-class="{'itemSmall': ctrl.name.length > 10, 'itemBig': ctrl.name.length <= 10}"></div>
```

Comment: Since the question was about a pure CSS solution it would be sexier to add a class accordingly and style that class in CSS.

Comment: @CaptainCarl you are correct, i will add this on answer.

Comment: Smart i don't think about this type of approach thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ng-class directive

```
<div class="item"
   ng-click="ctrl.clickFunction()"
   ng-class="{'css-class1':condition1, 'css-class2':condition2() }">
<div class="itemGlobalCode">{{::ctrl.name}}</div>
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.condition1 = true;
$scope.condition2 = function(input) {
     // or calculate,do something with the input
    return input.isTrue();
}
```